# How to configure biometric logon on Windows 10 WITHOUT enabling PIN?

Tags: windows-10, login, fingerprint, biometrics

In Windows 8.1, i could enable fingerprint logon on my laptop. In Windows 10 i get a message “You need to configure PIN logon to add another fingerprint”. I am currently using a password to login into Windows. A PIN would be unwieldy to enter, considering that it has to contain only numbers.